# JQ merge WooCommerce REST API responce

Tags: json, bash, parsing, woocommerce, jsonparser

Im trying to parse data from woocommerce from linux console.
Need to take only shipping info and item names with quantity.

im making curl request to `wp-json/wc/v2/orders/ORDER_ID`
then
`jq '{order_id:.id,ship_info:.shipping,items: (.line_items[] | {name , quantity} ) }'`
If order contains two items,  **jq** will return two objects
example:

```
{
  "order_id": 1234,
  "ship_info": {
    "first_name": "Sam",
    "last_name": "Fisher",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "24 Mega Drive",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "Eglinton",
    "state": "WA",
    "postcode": "6032",
    "country": "AU",
    "phone": ""
  },
  "items": {
    "name": "Black T-shirt",
    "quantity": 1
  }
}
{
  "order_id": 1234,
  "ship_info": {
    "first_name": "Sam",
    "last_name": "Fisher",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "24 Mega Drive",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "Eglinton",
    "state": "WA",
    "postcode": "6032",
    "country": "AU",
    "phone": ""
  },
  "items": {
    "name": "White T-shirt",
    "quantity": 1
  }
}
```

I want merge items and use item's name as a key and item's qty as a value. Please advice how to get output like this

```
{
  "order_id": 1234,
  "ship_info": {
    "first_name": "Sam",
    "last_name": "Fisher",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "24 Mega Drive",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "Eglinton",
    "state": "WA",
    "postcode": "6032",
    "country": "AU",
    "phone": ""
  },
  "items": {
    "White T-shirt": "1",
    "Black T-shirt": "1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current `jq` query you are iterating over the items **inside** a generated object. That's why you receive one object per item. Rather than merging them afterwards, don't separate them in the first place.

If you changed your query from

```sh
jq '{
  order_id: .id,
  ship_info: .shipping,
  items: (.line_items[] | {name, quantity})
}'
```

to just

```sh
jq '{
  order_id: .id,
  ship_info: .shipping,
  items: .line_items
}'
```

you'd probably already see that `.line_items` is actually an array.

To transform it according to your desired output, change that line to one of the followings. They should all yield the same result.

```
  items: (.line_items | map({(.name): .quantity}) | add)
```

```
  items: (INDEX(.line_items[]; .name) | map_values(.quantity))
```

```
  items: (reduce .line_items[] as $i ({}; .[$i.name] = .quantity))
```